# How to display HTML markup in Highlights.js

Tags: javascript, syntax-highlighting

I am working on [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/ng4tkw5j/). Why am I unable the to render the HTML markup in `highlights.js` snippet highlighter library?

```
<pre><code class="html">
 <a role="button" class="btn btn-default btn-block">Item 4</a>
</code></pre>

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('pre code').each(function(i, e) {hljs.highlightBlock(e)});
});
```

Comment: No idea about the highlights library, but in your fiddle, you have two different versions...

Comment: Thanks Mike, this is strange not sure where did come the second one!?

Comment: For the answer, I believe you still have to escape the HTML within the `code` block. In other words, use `&lt;a role="button" ... &lt;/a>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code that you send is actually correct but I guess that on Fiddle there is some characters that have been escape or not translate. So as suggested by Mike, you have to escape the html:

```
<pre><code class="html">
  &lt;a role="button" class="btn btn-default btn-block"&gt;Item 4&lt;/a&gt;
</code></pre>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ng4tkw5j/2/

I have tried with an other language like PHP, it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/x3NXY/